# How to filter one list based on two others

Tags: python, list, if-statement, floating-point

I have the following 3 lists:

```
minimal_values = ['0,32', '0,35', '0,45']
maximal_values = ['0,78', '0,85', '0,72']

my_list = [
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '190,00', '0,15'], 
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '189,90', '0,32'], 
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '189,38', '0,44'],
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '188,94', '0,60'],
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '188,49', '0,78'],
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '187,99', '0,70'],
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '190,76', '0,10'], 
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '190,16', '0,20'], 
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '189,56', '0,35'],
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '189,01', '0,40'],
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '188,13', '0,75'],
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '187,95', '0,85'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '190,20', '0,11'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '190,10', '0,31'], 
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '189,32', '0,45'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '188,61', '0,67'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '188,01', '0,72'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '187,36', '0,55']]
```

I'm trying to filter `my_list` based if `index [-1`] is between then the value in `minimal_values` and the value in `maximal_values`. Im also doing a substraction inside the list. So for Morocco I only want the rows where `index[-1]` is between `0,32` and `0,78` etc. The problem is that after `0,78` the values drops to `0,70` which means that row also satifies the `if` `statement`, while I dont want that row. Im not sure how to solve this problem.

**This is my code:**

```
price = 500

# Convert values to float.
minimal_values = [float(i.replace(',', '.')) for i in minimal_values]
maximal_values = [float(i.replace(',', '.')) for i in maximal_values]

# Collect all unique countries in a list.
countries = list(set(country[0] for country in my_list))

results = []
for l in my_list:
    i = countries.index(l[0])
    if minimal_values[i] <= float(l[-1].replace(',', '.')) <= maximal_values[i]:
        new_index_2 = price - float(l[-2].replace(',', '.'))
        l[-2] = new_index_2
        results.append(l)

print(results)
```

**This is my current output:**

```
[['Morocco', 'Meat', 310.62, '0,44'], 
['Morocco', 'Meat', 311.06, '0,60'], 
['Morocco', 'Meat', 311.51, '0,78'], 
['Morocco', 'Meat', 312.01, '0,70'], 
['Spain', 'Meat', 310.44, '0,35'], 
['Spain', 'Meat', 310.99, '0,40'], 
['Spain', 'Meat', 311.87, '0,75'], 
['Italy', 'Meat', 310.68, '0,45'], 
['Italy', 'Meat', 311.39, '0,67'], 
['Italy', 'Meat', 311.99, '0,72'], 
['Italy', 'Meat', 312.64, '0,55']]
```

**This is my desired output:**

```
[['Morocco', 'Meat', 310.62, '0,44'], 
['Morocco', 'Meat', 311.06, '0,60'], 
['Morocco', 'Meat', 311.51, '0,78'], 
['Spain', 'Meat', 310.44, '0,35'], 
['Spain', 'Meat', 310.99, '0,40'], 
['Spain', 'Meat', 311.87, '0,75'], 
['Italy', 'Meat', 310.68, '0,45'], 
['Italy', 'Meat', 311.39, '0,67'], 
['Italy', 'Meat', 311.99, '0,72']]
```

Comment: I don't think you've explained why you don't want the last row of Morocco to be in the output. It meets the criteria in that `.32 <= .70 <= .78`

Comment: Same comment.  Please explain more.

Comment: Because I only look to the ascending part. Not to the descending part.

Comment: If you run your code several times you will see that it gives you different results sometimes. That is because the line `countries = list(set(country[0] for country in my_list))` which sometimes gives a different order for the set. You are dependent on a specific order because you then use that to index into the `minimal_values` and `maximal_values` lists

Comment: For example, why is `['Morocco', 'Meat', '189,90', '0,32']` not included in your output since  `.32 <= .32 <= .78`